# how to pipe output of traced bash debugging?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to pipe the output of traced script as follows:

```
bash -x /path/to/a/script | more
```

or

```
bash -o xtrace /path/to/a/script | more
```

and

```
bash -x /path/to/script > a_file
```

or

```
bash -o xtrace /path/to/script > a_file`
```

but did not work. As it is file inside `/etc` i dont want to edit it and as the output is too long I cannot scroll back to see the desired output.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```bsh
bash -x /path/to/a/script |& more
```

`bash` xtrace output is written to the STDERR, while piping `|` you are just giving the STDOUT of `bash -x /path/to/a/script` to `more` or any other command on the right side of `|`.

`|&` will pipe both the STDOUT and STDERR to `more` so you can use them both with `more`.

Alternately if you are just concerned with piping the `xtrace` (STDERR) only, use this:

```
bash -x /path/to/script 2>&1 >/dev/null | more
```

While redirecting to a file, if you want to redirect both the script output and `xtrace` output use any one of the following:

```
bash -x /path/to/script &>/where/to/save
bash -x /path/to/script >/where/to/save 2>&1
```

If you want to redirect only the `xtrace`:

```
bash -x /path/to/script 2>/where/to/save
```

Comment: "2>" -- this redirects all of STDERR not just xtrace.

Answer (score 1):

> `bash -x /path/to/script 2> a_file`

should do the job , this way you pipe `stderr` to the file , as opposed to just `stdout`.